# React: Maximum update depth exceeded when running two react projects on port 3000 and port 3001

Tags: reactjs

When starting up a React project I saw the following message:

> Something is already running on port 3000 [it was another React
> project of mine].
>
> Would you like to run the app on another port instead? › (Y/n)

I agreed and it ran my project on port 3001, which mysteriously caused the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
    at checkForNestedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:23093)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21164)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:12639)
    at Router.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:471)
    at Router.js:34
    at listener (history.js:155)
    at history.js:173
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.notifyListeners (history.js:172)
    at setState (history.js:288)
    at history.js:402
    at Object.confirmTransitionTo (history.js:145)
    at replace (history.js:385)
    at Lifecycle.onUpdate (Redirect.js:53)
    at Lifecycle.componentDidUpdate (Lifecycle.js:9)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:19835)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:22803)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:22541)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:22381)
    at finishSyncRender (react-dom.development.js:21807)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21793)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21909)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24757)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24840)
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:16)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:33)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.1 (withProtectedLayout.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <Lifecycle> component:
    in Lifecycle (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Redirect (at authRoute.js:13)
    in Route (at authRoute.js:7)
    in AuthRoute (at App.js:82)
    in Switch (at App.js:58)
    in App (at src/index.js:20)
    in Router (at src/index.js:19)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:18)

react-dom.development.js:11102 Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
[stack trace removed]
```

Answer (score 0):

I later found that stopping my other project and letting this project run on port 3000 resolved the error but I have no idea why it solved it.

Comment: Nope that is not the reason . One of your project is causing the infinite re-render because as the error states you are setting the state in the componentDidUpdate or might be calling the setState inside a render . The error is not related to running the app in different port . You have mentioned you have stopped the other project and the error is stopped . So the problem is in it . Stop the project which works fine and start the other one . You should still see the error .

Comment: When either project is run separately, I do not get this error.